# Extract year from big date in postgreSQL ('date out of range for timestamp')

Tags: postgresql

I get an error "date out of range for timestamp" in the following situation:

```
select '1000000-01-01'::date; --> 1000000-01-01 -> ok!
select extract(year from ('1000000-01-01'::date)) -> date out of range for timestamp
select to_char('1000000-01-01'::date, 'YYYY') -> date out of range for timestamp
```

I guess the problem is that somewhere the date is converted to timestamp.

How to extract the year in my situation?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it seems any time you do an operation on a `date` it gets transformed to a `timestamp`. The best I could come up with:

```
 select split_part('1000000-01-01', '-', 1) as year;
  year   
---------
 1000000

--If value is actual date:

select split_part('1000000-01-01'::date::text, '-', 1) as year;
  year   
---------
 1000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That could be a solution, but my sample was just simplified. In the end I have a real date-field from the database. So you think that must be a bug and can only be overcome by a hack like split_part?

Comment: I don't know that it is bug, just that dates are converted to timestamps when being operated on. The folks that could tell you more can be found on [postgresql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/). I would suggest posting there also.